# How to run FSharp.Plotly (charts) non interactive?

Tags: f#

I want to create a console application that makes use of [FSharp.Plotly](https://github.com/muehlhaus/FSharp.Plotly) (charts) to show statistics. However, FSharp.Plotly seems only able to run in a .fsx file (documentation didn't mentioned .fs) I tried it in a .fsx file and it was a success, i was able to load a chart.

However, I want to be able to call the graphs (so a pop up appears) with a console application, how to achieve this?

Comment: are you getting some sort of error? have you tried compiling the code in the .fs file?

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work. To load the library i have to type something like this: #load @"directoryToLibrary.dll". The compiler than says that load doesn't work in a non interactive file, which i can understand. But don't know how to load it in a different way

Comment: Add it it as a reference to your project

Comment: I did. I installed the FSharp.Plotly with the NuGet Package Manager. It can be seen in the reference list. I use Visual Studio 2017 btw

Comment: `open Fsharp.Plotly`? and you should be good to go?

Comment: It works now indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use: `open Fsharp.Plotly` (it needs first to be seen in the references list).